# Strange infinite sum

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, polynomials

Let be $P$ and $Q$ two polynomials, and $deg Q =deg P +1$ (so, if $P=kx^2+...$, then $Q= jx^3+...$).

Let be $R=P/Q$.

Show that for every $\alpha>0$, there is a correct choice of $n(\alpha)$ such that every term of the sum $$S_{\alpha}=\sum_{n=n(\alpha)}^{\infty} (-1)^n R\left(2+n^{\alpha} \right)$$
is defined.
And show when this sum converges.

Comment: The first part is easy, $Q$ has some maximum root $r$, take $n(\alpha)$ large enough that $2+n^\alpha>r$. (In principle there could be some subtlety if $n(\alpha)$ is supposed to depend only on $\alpha$ and not on $Q$ but that's not possible.) For the second part, here's my hint: as $x \to \infty,R(x)=\Theta(x^\beta)$; what's $\beta$?

Comment: But $R=1/x + o(1/x)$? In this case for $x\to 0$ the general term of the sum is not defined!

Comment: What does $x\to 0$ matter? $\alpha>0$ so the argument of $R$ is large for large $n$.

Comment: So, the sum diverges for every $\alpha >0$, since we can't apply Leibniz rule(?)

Comment: It is easy to see what happens if $\alpha>1$. The more interesting question pertains to $0<\alpha \leq 1$ because as you say it is not clear that the Leibniz rule applies.

Comment: Also for $0<\alpha\le 1$ the general term is not decreasing. So the sum must diverges

Comment: Why is it not decreasing? In any case just the Leibniz rule failing does not tell you anything.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand.. Every function $f(x)= kx^b$ is clearly increasing also if $0<b\le 1$

Comment: Remember that this is all being plugged into $R$.

Comment: So if $R<0$ the general term is decreasing.. Thanks

Comment: ...No, it has nothing to do with the sign of $R$. You should really think in some detail about a particular example, like $P(x)=1,Q(x)=x$.

Comment: I would have $a_n =\frac{2+n^{\alpha}}{x}$. I don't know what you are trying to show me

Comment: No, you wouldn't. You would have $a_n=(-1)^n \frac{1}{2+n^\alpha}$.

Comment: Why $\frac{1}{2+n^{\alpha}}$?

Comment: Oh s**t. Now I understand that $(2+n^a)$ is the argument of $R$...

Comment: I thought that it was a product.. sorry for make you waste you time